# Print format being ignored or over-ridden?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, ansi-escape

I have a couple of fields I'd like to print, and if one of those fields hits a value, I'd like to print in red to warn.

I have some code to render in red that I cribbed from any number of SO posts ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python/21786287))

```python
def warning_text(text):
     CRED = '\033[31m'
     CEND = '\033[m'
     return CRED + text + CEND
```

Largely it works

```python
>>> print('test')
test
>>> print(warning_text('test'))
test
```

(imagine that second test is in red, I can't find the formatting to make it work)

But when I apply formatting, the red remains, but the formatting is lost:

```py
>>> print('{:>9}{:>9}'.format('test','test'))
     test     test
>>> print('{:>9}{:>9}'.format('test',warning_text('test')))
     testtest
```

(again, the second test in line 4 is red but I can't work out how to format this text)

I've tried other options for the function like this:

```py
>>> def warning_text(text):
...      CRED = '\033[31m'
...      CEND = '\033[m'
...      return '{} {} {}'.format(CRED,text,CEND)
```

without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The formatting interprets the ANSI codes as usual printable characters. So the red "test" consists of 5+4+3=12 characters and the formatting algorithm concludes that it shouldn't be prefixed with spaces to adjust it to the right.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I am slapping my head in embarrassment.